# ggplot2 tile scale limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

Apologies if this is a bit of an obvious question, but can anyone tell me how I can set the scale on a heatmap drawn with geom tile? I want to draw several heatmaps all on the same scale (e.g. drawn with the colours scaled to  a maximum of 10 even though on two of them the maximum is 5) and can't work it out.

An example:

```
mydata<-expand.grid(X1=1:8,Y1=1:5)
Z1<-floor(runif(40,min=0,max=6))
Z2<-floor(runif(40,min=0,max=11))

mydata<-cbind(mydata,Z1,Z2)

mydata<-data.frame(mydata)

p1 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=X1, y=Y1, z = Z1))
p1 <- p +geom_tile(aes(fill = Z1))

p2 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=X1, y=Y1, z = Z2))
p2 <- p +geom_tile(aes(fill = Z2))
```

p1 will be scaled between 0 and 4 whereas p2 will be scaled between 0 and 10. I'd like to draw both of them so that the colours are on the same scale - so "4" has the same colour in both heatmaps.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Read up on scales: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_manual.html

Comment: Thanks, I read that and I couldn't find anything useful. I'm probably being a bit dim, but could you point me at the relevant section?

Comment: Great explanation in the answer by @Troy, just make sure to choose a diverging or sequential palette http://geography.uoregon.edu/datagraphics/color_scales.htm something `RColorBrewer` (example here: http://www.compbiome.com/2010/12/r-using-rcolorbrewer-to-colour-your.html) can easily help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry misread the question first time round - how about this?

```
colors<-c("red","orangered","orange","yellow","lightyellow",
          "lightgreen","green","darkgreen","darkblue","purple")

df<-expand.grid(x=1:5,y=1:5,grp=1:4)     # fill in 4 grids
df$vals<-runif(100)*10                   # add some values between 0 & 10

ggplot(df) + geom_tile(aes(x,y,fill=vals)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ grp) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=colors,values=1:10,rescaler = function(x,...) x, oob = identity)
```

[image]

```
# and filtering out high numbers for some groups
ggplot(df[df$vals<=5|df$grp<3,]) + geom_tile(aes(x,y,fill=vals)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ grp) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=colors,values=1:10,rescaler = function(x,...) x, oob = identity)
```

[image]